# What is reason that two variables are the same, even should be different?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I'm trying to write plugin in minecraft (case opener). I have problem, because whenever variable current_item and variable next are the same, even should be different.

```
Inventory inv = Bukkit.createInventory(null, InventoryType.CHEST, "Losowanie");

ItemStack rnditem = new ItemStack(Material.STICK);

ItemStack current_item = new ItemStack(Material.APPLE);
ItemStack next = new ItemStack(Material.STICK);

for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {

    Random rand = new Random();

    switch(rand.nextInt(2)) {
        case 0:
            rnditem.setType(Material.DIAMOND);
            break;
        case 1:
            rnditem.setType(Material.GOLDEN_APPLE);
            break;
    }


    inv.clear();

    current_item = next;
    next = rnditem;

    inv.setItem(13, current_item);
    inv.setItem(14, next);

    p.updateInventory();

    Thread.sleep(i*100);
}
```

Comment: You make all 3 ItemStacks reference the same object when you write `current_item = next; next = rnditem;`. You'll need to make copies of those objects if you don't want changes to one to effect the others. I'd write an answer, but I have no idea wussy those objects are, so I can't really say how you'd go about copying them.

Comment: Also you should probably put `Random rand = new Random();` before the for loop

Comment: And curious that you sleep for an increasing amount of time each iteration of the loop, instead of a constant amount of time

Comment: @phflack It's intentional action, I wanted the movement of objects to be slower than making a loop. Whenever item must be drawn again, so `Random` must be in loop

Comment: So the first item should be instant, second after 100ms, third after another 200ms, and so on until it's a 1.5 second delay between items?  And not sure why `Random` must be in the loop, you're making a new random generator each time instead of reusing it.  `Random.nextInt(int)` will generate a new random int each time it's called

Comment: The delay makes sense for the slot machine feel, wasn't entirely sure what you were trying to create at first.  The delay should keep `Random` random, but it's normally better practice to reuse the same generator in this case instead of creating single use generators

Comment: Your question did hit the "Triage Review" bump (e.g. because its confusing)... you might want to extend your question tag to be more specific on the topic. Its now too general. Also fix your grammar and add some of the info you have mentioned in comments as text into the question itself by editing it. End of review > should hace send it to "requires editing". Wrongly clicked "looks okay"!

Comment: Ok, fixed, thank you for help. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Different variables are being used to hold a shifting reference, but `rnditem` is never set to a new reference

```
switch(rand.nextInt(2)) {
    case 0:
        rnditem.setType(Material.DIAMOND);
        break;
    case 1:
        rnditem.setType(Material.GOLDEN_APPLE);
        break;
}
```

Should instead be

```
switch(rand.nextInt(2)) {
    case 0:
        rnditem = new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND);
        break;
    case 1:
        rnditem = new ItemStack(Material.GOLDEN_APPLE);
        break;
}
```